# Get Axios frontend Promise to receive errors msg from Rails backend

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, error-handling, promise, axios

In Rails I'm returning:

```
render json: { errors: e.response.body.errors }, status: 400
```

In JavaScript I'm using Axios:

```
axios.patch('/settings/account', {}, {params: {...
    } })
  .then((e)=> {
    ...
    console.log('submitted')
  })
  .catch(function (error, res) {
    // only get error that gives 400, but not error msg here, res isn't here
    console.log(error);
  });
```

How do I get the `e.response.body.errors` on my frontend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Axios reject promises if the server response http status code is anything but 2xx. I see you are sending an error response from the server, but are you sending this response through a http error status? If you arent, the error isnt an error to axios, so the error would show in the "then()" hook, since the promise is resolved.

If you are, then you should see the error whithin `error.response.data`

Comment: Axios first catch the error if your server returns anything but 2xx. If the error has a response body, you should see the body in `error.response.data`. But its possible that axios is catching other errors, like if your server is having any trouble to send this error body. If it happen, you should see error whitin `error.message` or `error.request` or just `console.log(error)` to see what is happening.